# Como fazer aplicações gráficas em C e C++?

Tags: c, c++

Eu gostaria de saber como se faz apps com GUI em C e C++. Eu sei que a lógica, como os loops if/else, while, for, swith e do while continuam os mesmos, mas gostaria de saber como fazer uma janela, um botão, e algo interativo. Uso Linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Para C, você pode usar IUP: [Clique em mim](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parceiro, isso vai te ajudar: http://www.qt.io/developers/
Só estudar, entender como funciona e meter a mão na massa.

QT é mundialmente utilizado para desenvolvimento de softwares desktop, como também é possível desenvolver para android com QT. Bons estudos.

Comment: Eles também usam o QT para desenvolver o KDE e o Razor-qt, não é?

Comment: Isso, muitos softwares que utilizamos tem esse cara no meio. Da pra fazer muita coisa bacana com QT. Vale ressaltar que ele aceita até CSS para embelezar aplicações desktop.

Comment: É necessário ter o QT instalado na máquina que vai rodar a aplicação ou só na máquina para fazer o código?